# How make loop to append text blocks

Tags: animation-nodes

Stuck on making this a looped subprogram

Hi folks,
I'm new to this, so I hope I'm asking the correct way and in the correct place. I tried to scan this forum for answers, but couldn't find help. Basically, I'm trying to take the node tree shown below and make a simple loop to keep me from having to create another list element each time I add a text block.

Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the text blocks, get their texts, append them to a text list, join them as you wish:

[image: Node Tree 1]

To get a list of all text blocks, you can use this piece of code:

```
[text for text in bpy.data.texts]
```

Which you can possibly filter in anyway, for instance using the *Filter Text Block List*:

[image: Node Tree 2]